# Predicting Multiple Time Steps in a Time Series using LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I want to forecast, for example, `k` next points of a time series using LSTM in Keras.
I construct a data set starting from the beginning of a list containing all the points by selecting `0:p-1` points as input features and next `k` points i.e. `p:p+k-1` as the output features. I continue this procedure by taking `1:p` as input features and ... 
Finally I get two dataframes `X`, input data which is `txp` and `y`, output data which is `txk`. So, my problem has many-to-many structure based on [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/17245428/14640043/e4cdf91c-063f-11e6-8844-c89a9e134339.png).

```
X = X.values.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
y = y.values.reshape(y.shape[0], 1, y.shape[1])
```

and then the first layer of my network is:

```
model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
```

But here the time step is 1. My question is that how I can increase timesteps. Should I replicate some of the rows in `X` and `y`? Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I found the answer in the below link. I put the link just for future reference: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/keras-users/9GsDwkSdqBg/kV1Ep9E_BAAJ